# User matching query does not exist in view for Login Form

Tags: python, django

**LoginForm in forms.py**

```
class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(label='Username', max_length=30)
    password = forms.CharField(
        label='Password',
        widget = forms.PasswordInput(),
    )

    def clean_username(self):
        username = self.cleaned_data['username']

        try:
            User.objects.get(username = username)
            user.objects.get(username = username)
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            raise forms.ValidationError('Invalid Username or Password!')

    def clean_password(self):
        password1 = self.cleaned_data['password']
        username = self.cleaned_data['username']
        user = User.objects.get(username = username)
        password2 = user.password

        if user.check_password(password1):
            return password1
        else:
            raise forms.ValidationError('Invalid Username or Password!')
```

**login_page in views.py**

```
def login_page(request):
    template = get_template('login_page.html')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = LoginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            if user is not None:
                login(request, user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/user/username')

    else:
        form = LoginForm()

    variables = RequestContext(request, {
            'form': form
        })
    return render_to_response('login_page.html', variables)
```

**login_page.html template**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %}User Login{% endblock %}
{% block head %}User Login{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
{% if form.has_errors %}
    <p>Your username and password didn't match. 
       Please try again.</p>
{% endif %}
<form method="post" action=".">
<p><label for="id_username">Username:</label> 
{{ form.username }}</p>
<p><label for="id_password">Password:</label> 
{{ form.password }}</p>
<input type="submit" value="login" />
<input type="hidden" name="next" value="/" />
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

The above view when called from **localhost:8000/login/** results in a **User matching query does not exist** error. I can't exactly sense the reason. I am using the default authentication system used by Django 1.8.

I am new to Django. Please help me out.

Comment: Note that you don't have to write your own login form and view. Django has a built in [`login`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.login) view that uses the built in [`AuthenticationForm`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/default/#module-django.contrib.auth.forms).

Comment: No, you **must not** do this yourself. It is horribly insecure. **Do not**.

Comment: Yup.. Read about it and changed it. Thank you :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That exception comes from :

```
   user = User.objects.get(username = username)
```

in `clean_password`. You already know how to fix this error, you have done it in your `clean_username` by sorrounding that query by `try`, `except` to avoid this error.

Comment: Thank You so much. Works perfectly :)